# How do I enable audit logging for Identity Platform?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

We are switching our auth platform to Google's Identity Platform. Since our platform is HIPAA & SOC2 compliant, we are trying to enable audit logging for Identity Platform.

We tried going to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/audit and adding in Identity Platform but it seems like audit logs aren't available for this service.

**How do we enable audit logging (e.g. tracking when a user logs in and logs out) for the Identity Platform?**

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with HIPAA & SOC2, but if you want to log the user's login and logout, you may do so on your Backend.

#### Related reference

I suppose you are using Firebase Auth; I am using it too.
Unlike most people, my application is written in Ruby; there is no official Ruby SDK from Google.

They provide [low-level details about verifying the Firebase Auth tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) without using SDKs.
Upon reading the document, we will find that the Firebase Auth interface to the application is simply a JWT token issued by Google.

#### How can it be applied?

The user's login can be defined as a credential token generation; if we define them that way, the only person who can log the events is simply Google and only Google.

But we may also **count only token claims as a login**; which means unclaimed tokens do not count as a login. If there is no policy on HIPAA and SOC2 against this definition, you can log the events you are interested in with your Backend.

#### Implementation details

Everyone has different details; my application looks like this:

1. My Frontend signed a user in with Firebase Auth and got the token by `await user.getIdToken()`.
2. The token is then submitted to the Backend to be verified and exchanged with the credential used within my application. (For me, this is session cookies)
3. Use `onAuthStateChanged` to listen to Firebase logout events; when the logout occurs, we must also destroy the application credential exchanged in step 2.

For my application, I can insert the logging code in Step 2 and define it as a login and also in Step 3 as a logout.

#### Summary

My suggestion is to:

- Define login and logout more rigidly; don't keep it vague. Rigid and secure but also leaves room for implementation convenience and feasibility.
- Once you recognize that the policy itself is also possibly moving space, the path may show up.

Not sure if this is applicable to your situation, though.